# Правильно добавить и удалить элементы в список

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как правильно добавлять и удалять элементы из списка `RecyclerView`? Написала такой код, когда добавляю элементы вроде индексы правильно отображаются. Т.е. при запуске приложения создается 1 элемент, а когда добавляю еще один элемент позиция уже 2, 3 и т.д.

А вот когда удаляю элемент кажется не совсем правильно работаю с индексами.

Например если в списке два элемента и удаляю 2-ой элемент, то во всплывающем сообщении выводится "Удалено: 1" т.е. как будто удален элемент с индексом 1, а если в списке был  1 элемент и добавляю новый, то выводится "Добавлен: 2".

Правильно ли я вообще добавляю элементы и удаляю?

Адаптер

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context,List<String> list) {
        mDataSet = list;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public EditText editText;
        public Button btnDelete;

        public ListViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            btnDelete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        ListViewHolder vh = new ListViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.editText.setText("Элемент:  " + mDataSet.get(position));

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mDataSet.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);

                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mDataSet.size());

                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Удалено: " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Элементов всего: ", getItemCount() + "");

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Button btnAdd;
    private RecyclerView rvList;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnAdd= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        final List<String> itemsList = new ArrayList();

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,itemsList);
        ((MyAdapter) mAdapter).setImageButtonClick(this);

        rvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        itemsList.add(position++, "" + position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                position = mAdapter.getItemCount();

                itemsList.add(position++,"" + position);

                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

                rvList.scrollToPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Добавлен: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Элементов всего: ", mAdapter.getItemCount() + "");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы не учитываете что в Java массивы начинаются не с 1, а с 0!

Т.е. у вас два элемента [0, 1] вы удаляете 2ой и вам правильно высвечивается что удален элемент с индексом "1".

Во втором случае вы присваиваете переменной position размер массива т.е. 1. Потом вы его инкрементируете и вам выдает что добавлен 2ой элемент!

Comment: А как правильно сделать?

Comment: если мы говорим о том как правильно вывести на экран значение то там достаточно сделать -1 к вашему значению. ("Удалено: " + (position -1)). Если говорить о том как добавить, то вам не надо указывать позицию добавления и так же вычесть единицу  
  (position = mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
                itemsList.add("" + position);)

Comment: Спасибо.. А вообще сам подход к добавлению и удалению элементов правильный или есть способ лучше?

Comment: Для этого случая думаю что других вариантов особо и нет. Ну из того что можно сделать лучше это к примеру вынести логику как таковую в другой класс, например презентер если использовать MVP. Но это совершенно отдельная тема. Ещё хорошим тоном для RecyclerView является создание DiffUtils класса.

Comment: А что за класс DiffUtils ? Что он должен делать? и еще такой вопрос: нумерация элементов в recyclerview начинается с 0 или 1?

Comment: Все массивы, списки в Java начинаются с 0. DiffUtil сравнивает старые данные с новыми и обновляет только те элементы которые изменились. В вашем случае он не особо нужен, но если к примеру вы будете передавать в адаптер список а он от старого будет отличаться только несколькими элементами, метод notifyDataSetChanged обновит весь список. Подробнее о классе и его реализации https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html

Comment: Списки да, начинаются с 0, но getAdapterPosition() когда нажимаю на первый элемент возвращает 1, поэтому спрашивала. А про обновление нескольких элементов - это пока мне не нужно. Список будет довольно короткий 3-5 элементов.